# Is there an ad-hoc tally table in Advantage Database Server?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am aware that SQL Server has master..spt_values.
I'm interested in an analogue of this table in Advantage Database Server.

Comment: What for exactly?

Comment: I need to check every character of a string. Of course, I could write SUBSTRING(field_name, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(field_name, 2, 1), SUBSTRING(field_name, 3, 1), etc. But this is not very convenient. If the field is 20 characters wide, I have to write SUBSTRING 20 times..

Comment: I would like to write for example: `SUBSTRING(field_name, N, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D'`

Comment: If you can provide a full working SQL Server example using spt_values I'll try to write something equivalent that works with ADS

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect writing SUBSTRING 20 times will result in the fastest solution, so the fact it is "not very convenient" seems irrelevant to me. You could easily generate the query programmatically.